# Why is my screen going black for a second and muting the sound output when watching a video?

Tags: windows-10, audio, display, hdmi, intel-graphics

I recently bought a Lenovo IdeaCentre Mini with Windows 10 Pro 20H2, i5-10400T and Intel UHD Graphics 630, and I am using it with a Lenovo Q24i monitor connected via HDMI.

When opening a site like Netflix, the screen goes black for a second, and the sound is muted permantely. I tried a few things (including getting the latest updates on Windows and the graphics driver), but ultimately discovered that I have to disconnect the HDMI cable briefly to restore the sound output.

Does anyone have an explanation as to what causes this behavior, and how I might fix it?

Comment: Most likely it has something to do with HDCP the content protection system that encrypts the HDMI signals to prevent video ripping. HDCP seems to be activated when requested by the Netflix video. and then something goes wrong in the switch from non-HDCP to HDCP mode. Make sure you are using the latest indel display drivers. If there is an option to always enable HDCP try to activate it.

Comment: @Robert: Thanks for the hint. I didn't know about this, and will check it out.

Comment: what are the specs for your HDMI cable? they are definitely not all created equal.

Comment: @FrankThomas: I have not checked it yet, but since I just used a cable lying around, it might in fact be a reason. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issues seems to stem from the refresh rate of the display. I changed it from 75 Hz to 60 Hz, the sound output of the display works fine now.